# Hibernate storing derived property

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class persisted by Hibernate with a derived property `isComplete`.

```
@Entity
class Container {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column private String oneFish;
    @Column private String twoFish;
    @Column private String redFish; 
    @Column private String blueFish;

    public Boolean isComplete(){
        return oneFish != null 
               && twoFish != null  
               && redFish != null 
               && blueFish != null;
    }
}
```

How do I get Hibernate to persist isComplete to the database so that other (non-hibernate) access can see the value?

Comment: Here's a similar question from the hibernate forum, they suggest calculating it within the java code, and not persisting it separately. https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=960065

Comment: if you calculate it in the Java code, it cannot be indexed by the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you annotated the method with `@Column` it will get persisted (you may have to specify `@AccessType` / `@Access` on the entity)

But you shouldn't do that. Store all the other values and compute the `isComplete` whenever you need it. It is not an expensive operation. You can even 'cache' it in a `@Transient Boolean` property, but it need not go the the database.

Comment: I want it to go to the database, that's the point. I want this derived column on the database.

Comment: why? You are creating many potential problems with that (anyway, my first paragraph answers your question)

Comment: As Paul said, this is for the benefit of other consumers of the data in the database - which are applications not running his code. The computation of completeness is domain logic (albeit apparently very simple domain logic); having every consumer implement it would introduce duplication, and with it, the risk of a whole class of bugs.

Comment: on the other hand, it would mean that you should always recompute the derived value if any of the others changes. Which, I think, can potentially introduce more bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XML Hibernate mappings, but if I understand Hibernate annotations correctly, you can annotate isComplete() as @Column and provide a do-nothing setter setComplete().